# R: Test if one character vector is contained in another in the same order

Tags: r

Using R, if I have a character vector `a`, how can I determine whether all its elements are contained *in the same order* somewhere within character vector `b`?

```
a <- letters[1:5]
b <- letters
c <- sample(letters)
```

In other words, where `a` is contained in order in `b`, but not in order in `c`.

Answer (score 1):

`paste` them together and then use `grepl`?

```
> grepl(paste(a,collapse = ""),c(paste(b,collapse = ""),paste(c,collapse = "")))
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```